# Взять содержимое из json php

Tags: php, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть такой код

```
<?php 
//адрес сайта
$url = '=';
// получаем содержимое сайта
$json = file_get_contents($url);
// преобразуем в массив
$array = json_decode($json, true);
// выводим значение переменной contactId
echo $array['orders']['orderid'];
?>
```

И такой json:

```
{"status":"ok","orders":[{"orderid":"29760","number":"29760","ordercode":"2013983770","ordername":"sx \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0426\u0438\u0444\u0440\u0430","ordersource":false,"clientid":"13121","clientname":"\u0412\u044f\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0430\u0432 \u0414\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043b\u044c\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e","clientemail":"sl@y.ua","clientphone":"","clientaddress":"","managerid":"5","cdate":"2018-01-18 13:37:38","dateto":"2018-10-17 13:37:00","deliveriID":"0","deliverinote":"","deliveriprice":"0.00","paymentid":"0","storagetoid":"0","storagetoexternalid":"","sum":"0.00","margin":"0.00","sumbase":"0.00","currency":"UAH","statusid":"159","statusname":"\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0430\u0437","statuscolor":"#ff6969","workflowid":"25","workflowname":" \u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430","contractorid":"0","contractorname":null,"customfields":[{"key":"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0447\u0438\u043d\u0430\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430","name":"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0447\u0438\u043d\u0430 \u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430","value":"\u0418\u0433\u043d\u043e\u0440"}],"products":[],"clientcompany":"\u0414\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043b\u044c\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e \u0412\u044f\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0430\u0432","clientcode":"22986425","weight":0,"gabarite":0}]}
```

Не могу вывести количество orders.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: `orders` это массив, потенциально там может быть несколько элементов. Так что либо разберитесь какой их элементов вам нужен, либо берите первый `$array['orders'][0]['orderid']`

Comment: @teran а если все нужны order, как взять все?

Comment: `foreach($array['orders'] as $o){ echo $o['orderid']; }` примерно так

Comment: @teran а как их разграничить? допустим поместить каждый orderid в ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

вы не совсем верно обращаетесь к обработанному массиву. После обработки json_decode

массив имеет вид:

```
Array
(
    [status] => ok
    [orders] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [orderid] => 29760
                    [number] => 29760
                    [ordercode] => 2013983770
                    [ordername] => sx для Цифра
                    [ordersource] => 
                    [clientid] => 13121
                    [clientname] => Вячеслав Данильченко
                    [clientemail] => sl@y.ua
                    [clientphone] => 
                    [clientaddress] => 
                    [managerid] => 5
                    [cdate] => 2018-01-18 13:37:38
                    [dateto] => 2018-10-17 13:37:00
                    [deliveriID] => 0
                    [deliverinote] => 
                    [deliveriprice] => 0.00
                    [paymentid] => 0
                    [storagetoid] => 0
                    [storagetoexternalid] => 
                    [sum] => 0.00
                    [margin] => 0.00
                    [sumbase] => 0.00
                    [currency] => UAH
                    [statusid] => 159
                    [statusname] => Отказ
                    [statuscolor] => #ff6969
                    [workflowid] => 25
                    [workflowname] =>  система
                    [contractorid] => 0
                    [contractorname] => 
                    [customfields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => Причинаотказа
                                    [name] => Причина отказа
                                    [value] => Игнор
                                )

                        )

                    [products] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [clientcompany] => Данильченко Вячеслав
                    [clientcode] => 22986425
                    [weight] => 0
                    [gabarite] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Как видите, вы пропустили ключ 0

Поэтому вывести нужные данные вы можете вот так:

```
echo $array['orders'][0]['orderid'];
echo $array['orders'][0]['number'];
```

А если заказов у вас много и нужно из каждого забирать указанные поля, то обычным перебором:

```
$orders = [];

foreach ($array['orders'] as $order) {
   $orders[$order['orderid']] = $order['number']; // ключи это ID заказов, значения это номера. Тут уж в зависимости от задачи как нужно укомплектовать значения
}
```

при такой обработке данных можно отдельно вывести все ID заказов при помощи

```
echo implode (', ', array_keys($orders)) // ID заказов в строку через запятую
echo implode (', ', $orders) // номера заказов в строку через запятую
```

[implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) - ссылка на доки

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php) - ссылка на доки

Comment: Подскажите, если есть несколько order как получить из их всех информацию?

Comment: Можно конкретнее? я ответ дополнил. в каком виде нужно получить данные после обработки массива? На выходе должно быть 2 массива? с orderID и number отдельно? или как?

Comment: Мы получаем массив с большим количеством orderid. Как разграничить эти orderid, поместив каждый в ссылку?

Comment: не совсем понял про ссылку. каждый orderID должен иметь формат <a href="/page/orderID">ссылка</a> ?

Comment: Верно, так же не записывается все odred id в текстовый файл а только один

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r ($array->orders);

print_r ($array->orders[0]->orderid);
```

-если есть несколько order как получить из их всех информацию?

```
foreach($array->orders as $order) {
   echo $order->orderid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

orders это массив, который может содержать n-количество массивов. В вашем случае он один, с индексом 0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо обращаться по индексу (если точно известно количество вложенных массивов)

```
$array['orders'][0]['orderid'];
```

Либо пробежать циклом foreach (если нужно обработать все массивы, в том случае если их будет больше одного)

```
foreach ($array['orders'] as $item)
{
    echo $item['orderid'];
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как допустим все эти orderid записать в txt файл или в свой json массив. Если делать так то записывается только один file_put_contents(
        'chat.json', 
        json_encode(['command' => $item['orderid']], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) 
    );